# Changing the font familiy in Rubens / Roomle Configurator SDK Integration

Tags: roomle

I want to change the font familiy because we don't want to use Lato from Google Fonts.

I added this code to the options, but Rubens still loads Lato:

```
"skin": {
    "font-family": "vFutura-Regular",
    "font-family-url": "fonts/vfutura-regular.woff"
},
```

How can custom fonts be used inside Rubens?

Answer (score 0):

By design it's currently not possible to change the font family or font size in the Roomle Rubens Configurator.